# The "UpdateBuildNumberDropLocation" task failed unexpectedly

Tags: visual-studio, wcf, tfs, build, branching-and-merging

I just created a new build definition for WCF services project via Visual Studio 2013 in TFS.
Fed it a Build Process Template that works for other similar pre-created build for the same project.
When I run the build I get the following error:

> C:\Builds\abc\xyz\pqr\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj (187): The
>   "UpdateBuildNumberDropLocation" task failed unexpectedly. The build number '<################>_1.0.2.4' already exists for build definition.

I searched through online but I didn't any root cause for it, what could be the possible reason?

Comment: Did you ever delete a build ?

Comment: Nope. But when after deleting and crating a new I am getting mapping error.

Comment: This occurs  when you have a workspace clash on the build server. Maybe you have created a new build definition with the same name as a previous build definition. I created build with name of removed build and get the mapping error as well. As a workaround rename your build definition to something unique.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of this issue maybe when you delete the builds, even though it doesn’t show up in the UI anymore, it only gets marked as deleted in the database. To get rid of this build completely you actually have to destroy it using `tfsbuild destroy` command.

> Open the Visual Studio Command Prompt and you can run the tfsbuild
>   destroy command in below mentioned syntax.
>
> ```
> C:\WINDOWS\system32>tfsbuild destroy /collection:http://TFSServer:8080/tfs/defaultcollection /builddefinition:"TeamProject\BuildDefinitionName" BuildNumber 1.0.2.4
> ```

More details please take a look this similar issue: [TF42064: The build number already exists for build definition error in TFS2010](http://geekswithblogs.net/jehan/archive/2011/04/23/tf42064-the-build-number-already-exists-for-build-definition-error.aspx)

---

**Update**

The mapping error occurs  when you have a workspace clash on the build server. Maybe you have created a new build definition with the same name as a previous build definition. I created build with name of removed build and get the mapping error as well.

As a workaround: try to rename your build definition to something unique.